# GlobalKey in InheritedWidget causing re-parent

Tags: flutter

Is passing a GlobalKey down the tree using an InheritedWidget an antipattern? The stateful widget using that key is re-created (i.e. a new state this initState/disposed) every time its subtree is re-built.

My InheritedWidget looks like:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../widgets/carousel.dart';
import '../widgets/panel/panel.dart';

class _CarouselKey extends GlobalObjectKey<CarouselState> {
  const _CarouselKey(Object value) : super(value);
}

class _ProgressiveChatHeaderKey extends GlobalObjectKey<PanelScaffoldState> {
  const _ProgressiveChatHeaderKey(Object value) : super(value);
}

class DimensionScopedKeyProvider extends InheritedWidget {
  final _CarouselKey parallelBubbleCarouselKey;
  final _ProgressiveChatHeaderKey progressiveChatHeaderKey;

  final String keyString;

  DimensionScopedKeyProvider({
    Key key,
    @required this.keyString,
    @required Widget child,
  })  : parallelBubbleCarouselKey = _CarouselKey(keyString),
        progressiveChatHeaderKey = _ProgressiveChatHeaderKey(keyString),
        super(key: key, child: child);

  static DimensionScopedKeyProvider of(BuildContext context) {
    return (context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(DimensionScopedKeyProvider)
        as DimensionScopedKeyProvider);
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(DimensionScopedKeyProvider oldWidget) => oldWidget.keyString != keyString;
}
```

And this InheritedWidget is rendered with a constant `keyString`, meaning that 1) `updateShouldNotify` always returns `false` and 2) the hashCode of the GlobalKeys passed to my build methods via `DimensionScopedKeyProvider.of()` are always identical.

The stateful widget builds something like

```dart
GlobalKey<PanelScaffoldState> get _headerKey => //
  DimensionScopedKeyProvider.of(context).progressiveChatHeaderKey;

// ...

PanelScaffold(
  key: _headerKey,
  // ...
)
```

When I change a property that affects the subtree that the `PanelScaffold` lives in, though, a new `PanelScaffoldState` is created and the old one is disposed, even though the widget tree hasn't changed structure and the `_headerKey` hasn't changed either.

Answer (score 0):

I also able to solve this problem, **but I have no idea why it works**.

The solution is to cache the access to the GlobalKey in `didChangeDependencies`

```dart
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _headerKey ??= DimensionScopedKeyProvider.of(context).progressiveChatHeaderKey;
  }
```

.... and now everything is working as expected again—the rebuilds re-parent the existing state.

**Does anyone know why caching the getter to the GlobalKey is the key here?**

Comment: My best guess here is that while the `key.value` is equal, the fact that you rebuild the `GlobalObjectKey` in the constructor is triggering the rebuild somehow